# Spark Map to Dataset Row

Tags: java, apache-spark, java-8, parquet

I am trying to create RDD using Dataset but having trouble finding a way to map to each of the Dataset Row.

```
Dataset<POJO> df1 = session.read().parquet(tableName).as(Encoders.bean(POJO.class));
```

Using the following approach

```
    JavaRDD<List<Tuple3<Long, Integer, Double>>> tempDatas1 = df1.map(r -> new MapFunction<POJO, List<Tuple3<Long, Integer, Double>>>(){
        //@Override
        public List<Tuple3<Long, Integer, Double>> call(POJO row) throws Exception
        {

        // Get the sample property, remove leading and ending spaces and split it by comma
        // to get each sample individually
        List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> samples = zipWithIndex((row.getSamples().trim().split(",")));

        // Gets the unique identifier for that s.
        Long snp = row.getPos();

        // Calculates the hamming distance.
        return samples.stream().map(t -> {
            String alleles = t._1();
            Integer patient = t._2();

            List<String> values = Arrays.asList(alleles.split("\\|"));

            Double firstAllele = Double.parseDouble(values.get(0));
            Double secondAllele = Double.parseDouble(values.get(1));

            // Returns the initial S id, p id and the distance in form of Tuple.
            return new Tuple3<>(snp, patient, firstAllele + secondAllele);
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    });
```

Getting `cannot resolve method map(<lambda expression>)` error on the `map` in `df1.map(r ->`.

Comment: can you post the full stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Please use df1.toJavaRDD() or df1.rdd() instead of directly writing map on top of the dataset. Better first convert your dataset to rdd and map it and store the output in rdd again.
Because dataset mapping doesn't give a JavaRDD or JavaPairRDD as the output of the transformation without converting the dataset in to rdd first.